# How do I access a numeric key in firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I'm quite new to Reactjs and Firebase so I'd need help.

[image: This is my database.]

I need to retrieve the data from the "0","1","2" keys (i.e. "Price", "Title", etc.) like I do with the "user" one.
In this parent component (Dashboard.js) I connect to the database:

```
import { useState,  useEffect } from "react";
import OrderedItems from "./OrderedItems";
import classes from "./Dashboard.module.css";
import dash from '../../assets/dash.jpg';
import { auth } from "../../firebase";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
const Dashboard = () => {
  const [ord, setOrd] = useState([]);
  const history = useHistory();
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchLps = async () => {
      const query = `${auth.currentUser.uid}/Orders.json` 
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://beatles-app-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/" + query
      );

      const responseData = await response.json();
console.log(responseData);
      const loadedOrd = [];

      for (const key in responseData) {
        loadedOrd.push({
          id: key,
          orderedItems: responseData[key].orderedItems,
      
        });
      }
     
      setOrd(loadedOrd);
     // setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchLps().catch((err) => {
      let errorMessage =
        "Something went wrong on our server! Please try again later.";
      alert(errorMessage);
      history.replace("/");
    });
  }, [history]);

  const OrdList = ord.map((things) => (
    <OrderedItems 
    key={things.id}
    id={things.id}
    orderedItems={things.orderedItems}
    />
    ));
  return (
    <section className={classes.cont}>
       <div className={classes.welcome}> 
       <h1 className={classes.h1}>Welcome to your Dashboard!</h1>
     
       <h3 className={classes.h3}> You can now start to shop. Go to the Shop page, select your favorite albums and go to Cart 
          in order to submit your order.</h3><br/>
         
          </div>
{OrdList}
      <img src={dash}  alt="" width="100%" />
    </section>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

console.log(responseData) output:
[image]
I retrieve the data in this child component (OrderedItems.js) using this syntax {props.user.address} (for example in this case I get "street" which is correct):

```
const OrderedItems = (props) => {
  return (
    <section>
      <div>
        <p>{props.user.address}</p> // THIS WORKS
<p>{props.orderedItems.0.Price}</p> // THIS DOESN'T WORK BECAUSE OF THAT 0 WHICH IS THE NAME OF THE FIREBASE KEY
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default OrderedItems;
```

Now the problem is that I can't do it with the above mentioned keys as the following syntax is not allowed because of that 0 number {props.orderedItems.0.Price}.

What should I do? The database structure is created automatically as I'm entering orders of multiple items using the POST method. So I suppose that the solution would be either to use a proper syntax (which I don't know at the moment) in order to access the data or to populate the database in a different way (but I don't think it is possible as Firebase does it on its own).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're asking. Which line of the code you shared doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Thank you Frank for your reply. I'm sorry it was not clear. I edited the code in OrderedItems component you can see above. I hope it's clearer now. :)

Comment: Isn't that just an array? So just reference the elements directly using `<p>{props.orderedItems[0].Price}</p>`

Comment: If you `console.log(responseData)`, what does it output? Please include both that statement and its output in your question.

Comment: Hello everyone. Maljukan's reply solved my issue. Thank you very much for your help! Frank I have included that in my question anyway :). Thank you!